# Linq: Selecting a new List<Guid> in C#

Tags: c#, linq

Using **linq** I am trying to get a **List[Guid]**, but I am not able to.

I tried this:

```
var myGuidList = from x in
                 mydatasource
                 where x.Field==value
                 select new Guid(){x.TheGuid};   <- Problem here
```

Comment: if X.TheGuid is of type Guid, then `select x.TheGuid` should be enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not clear what the type of `TheGuid` property is but if it is a string you could use the following:

```
IEnumerable<Guid> myGuidList = 
    from x in mydatasource
    where x.Field == value
    select new Guid(x.TheGuid);
```

And if it is a Guid, well, you could select it directly:

```
IEnumerable<Guid> myGuidList = 
    from x in mydatasource
    where x.Field == value
    select x.TheGuid;
```

and if you want to get a `List<Guid>`, simply use the `.ToList()` extension method on the result:

```
List<Guid> guids = myGuidList.ToList();
```

Answer (score 5):

Why do you need to create a new instance of a `Guid` if you already have one?

```
var myGuids = from x in
              mydatasource
              where x.Field == value
              select x.TheGuid;
```

(assuming that `x.TheGuid` is a `Guid` of course)

If you want a `List<Guid>`:

```
List<Guid> myGuidList = myGuids.ToList();
```

Note that `Guid` ha no [conctructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.guid.aspx) that takes a `Guid` (makes little sense anyway) or a parameterless constructor and it also has no property(just a field `Empty`), that's why your code cannot compile.